# Minor change to SQL SERVER query causes extremely slow execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I dont understand whats functionally different about these 2 queries that would make them so different. First my initial query:

```
SELECT * FROM XSales_Code SC
    WHERE SC.Status = 1
        AND SC.SCode NOT IN
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT SCode FROM XTransactions_01
            WHERE Last_Mdt > '2012-01-01'
                AND SCode IS NOT NULL
            )
        AND SC.Last_Mdt < '2014-01-01'
ORDER BY Last_Mdt desc
```

This took 13 minutes and 6 seconds to execute. Since I'm used to simple queries like this taking several seconds rather then several minutes I played around with and made this query which is, at least in my eyes, equivalent:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SCode INTO #TEMP1 FROM XTransactions_01
WHERE Last_Mdt > '2012-01-01'
    AND SCode IS NOT NULL

SELECT * FROM XSales_Code SC
    WHERE SC.Status = 1
        AND SC.SCode NOT IN
            (
            SELECT Scode FROM #TEMP1
            )
        AND SC.Last_Mdt < '2014-01-01'
ORDER BY Last_Mdt desc

DROP TABLE #TEMP1
```

The difference is this query takes 2 seconds to execute vs the 13 minutes above. Whats going on here?

Comment: I had not. I think this is the culprit. Here's the long time table:
...Table 'XTransactions_01'. ... logical reads 300636371...

Short time table:
...XTransactions_01'.... logical reads 43380...

Comment: And I did grab the execution plans this time however I don't know how to read them..

Comment: If you see index scans as opposed to index seeks in the query plan, that is the easiest thing to look for.  A scan means that it has to read all of the data in the index, because the columns with the criteria are not indexed columns.  Also--physical reads is the "real" killer if you're seeing those in the stats as that means it had to actually go to disk instead of being able to get it from memory.

Comment: You could also try to do this using not exists, if works better : "AND not exists (select 1 from XTransactions_01 X where X.SCode = SC.SCode and Last_Mdt > '2012-01-01')".  Also, looking at estimated and actual row count in actual plan might help to understand why the query plan goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you're using a "correlated subquery", which executes for every row in `XSales_Code` that passes the `Status = 1 AND Last_Mdt < '2014-01-01'` conditions.

Think of it like this: `XSales_Code` is filtered by `Status = 1 AND Last_Mdt < '2014-01-01'`, then SQL Server scans each row of this intermediate result, and for every single row it executes your `SELECT DISTINCT SCode FROM XTransactions_01...` query to see if the row should be included.

Your second query executes the correlated subquery the same number of times, but it's faster because it's executing against a smaller table.

Generally, the fastest way to do a `NOT IN` query is to left join to the "not in" subquery and then omit any rows where the left-joined column is null. This gets rid of the correlated subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM XSales_Code SC
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT SCode FROM XTransactions_01
    WHERE Last_Mdt > '2012-01-01'
        AND SCode IS NOT NULL
) whatevs ON SC.SCode = whatevs.SCode
WHERE SC.Status = 1
  AND SC.Last_Mdt < '2014-01-01'
  AND whatevs.SCode IS NULL
ORDER BY Last_Mdt desc
```

This is hard to explain, but try running the query above without the second-to-last line (`AND whatevs.SCode IS NULL`) and you'll see how `whatevs.SCODE` has a value when the condition is "IN" and is null when the condition is "NOT IN".

Finally, I want to stress that correlated subqueries aren't inherently evil. Generally they work just fine for an `IN` condition and plenty of other use cases, but for a `NOT IN` condition they tend to be slow.